# Modified Dini derivative of real-valued function $f \colon (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is non-negative implies $f$ is non-decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question:** Is it true that if $f \colon (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is so that $\liminf_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \geq 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. Then, $f$ is non-decreasing in $(a,b)$?

**My attempt:** If $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ then using the result of Dini-derivatives of continuous functions, $f$ is non-decreasing in $(a,b)$.

However, if $f$ is not continuous on $(a,b)$ would this assertion hold in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true: If $f:(a,b) \to \Bbb R$ satisfies
$$ \tag 1
\forall x \in (a, b): \, \liminf_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \geq 0
$$
then $f$ is non-decreasing. The continuity of $f$ is not needed for that conclusion.

It suffices to prove that $f$ is non-decreasing under the stronger assumption
$$ \tag 2
\forall x \in (a, b): \, \liminf_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} > 0 \, .
$$
If $f$ satisfies $(1)$ then $f(x) + \epsilon \cdot x$ satisfies $(2)$ for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, so that $f(x) + \epsilon \cdot x$ is non-decreasing. With $\epsilon \to 0$ it follows that $f$ is non-decreasing.

So let us assume that $f$ satisfies $(2)$ and fix $c, d \in (a, b)$ with $c < d$. We want to show that $f(c) \le f(d)$.

$\liminf_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} > 0$ implies that $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \ge 0$ in a neighborhood of $x$, so there is a $\delta_x > 0$ such that
$$ 
\begin{split}
 y \in (x - \delta_x, x) &\implies f(y) \le f(x) \, ,\\
 z \in (x, x + \delta_x) &\implies f(x) \le f(z)  \, .
\end{split} \tag{$*$}
$$
Now consider all open intervals $I_u = (c, u)$ with the property that $f(z) \ge f(c)$ for $z \in I_u$. $(*)$ at $x=c$ show that such intervals exist. The union of all such intervals $I_u$ is either equal to $(c, b)$, or equal to $(c, e)$ with some $e < b$.

The second case is not possible: Using $(*)$ at $x=e$ shows that
$$
 f(c) \le f(e - \delta_e/2) \le f(e) \le f(z)
$$
for $z \le e \le e + \delta_e$, so that $f(z) \ge f(c)$ for all $z \in I_u$ with $u = e+ \delta_e > e$.

So the union of all intervals $I_u$ with the property that $f(z) \ge f(c)$ for $z \in I_u$ is equal to $(c, b)$. In particular, $d$ in contained in that union, so that $f(d) \ge f(c)$.

Comment: do you mind explaining the second last paragraph. Taking $x = e$ under $(*)$, I get 
$$z \in (e, e + \delta_e) \implies f(e) \leq f(z)$$ and suppose $I_u = (c,e) \subsetneq (c,b)$ then
$$z \in (c,e) \iff f(z) \geq f(c)$$ and 
$$z \in [e,b) \implies f(z) < f(c)$$

I'm not sure how u reach to conclusion that $f(z) \geq f(c)$ for all $z \in I_u$ with some $u >e$.

Comment: @L-JS: For $e \le z \le e+ \delta_e$ is $f(c) \le f(e-\delta_2/2) \le f(e) \le f(z)$, so that $f(z) \ge f(c)$ for all $z \in I_u$ with $u = e + \delta_e$. – The idea is to prove that the “largest” interval $(c, e)$ on which $f$ is $\ge f(c)$ is necessarily equal to $(c, b)$.

Comment: I see thank you, great answer!